# Product as either physical or virtual

Tags: product, virtual

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this? I want to offer a product that the customer can choose to receive physically or as a download.

I could set this as a custom option but then shipping will still show at checkout if the product hasn't been built as a virtual.

Any way around this?

Comment: So it's more of a shipping kind of option? Send this product to me or I want to download it?

Comment: It's a greetings card. Choose to have us print and send it or receive it as a pdf and print it yourself. I guess it needs to be an option on the product page so user can see price difference (tiered pricing for physical product, 1 set price for virtual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a fully working solution, but I have an idea.
the shipping steps show in the checkout if the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::isVirtual`.
This method looks like this:

```
public function isVirtual()
{
    $isVirtual = true;
    $countItems = 0;
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $_item) {
        /* @var $_item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        if ($_item->isDeleted() || $_item->getParentItemId()) {
            continue;
        }
        $countItems ++;
        if (!$_item->getProduct()->getIsVirtual()) {
            $isVirtual = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $countItems == 0 ? false : $isVirtual;
}
```

this basically checks if you have a product that's not virtual. If there is one then the quote is not virtual.
You can try to change this line:

```
if (!$_item->getProduct()->getIsVirtual()) {
```

to something that fits your needs.
I mean, instead of `$_item->getProduct()->getIsVirtual()` check if the item has a special custom option that makes it virtual or something like that.